# Difference between daily and normal version of vlc

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I went to the Ubuntu software centre to download vlc media player. But when I searched for it there are two versions. One is simply "daily". The other is "2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4". What's the difference between the two and which one should I install?

Comment: Did you add a PPA?

Comment: vlc version 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 has passed the tests for Ubuntu. I don't know the details about vlc's daily version, but usually the daily version of some software means that it is the bleeding edge version, and still needs testing. So if you enjoy testing, you can try the daily version, but if you want a reliable tool you should use the version from Ubuntu's repositories, now "2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4".

Comment: @muru I have a new Ubuntu installation and I did add one or two ppas. Maybe the daily is from one of them.

Comment: @sudodus So I should probably install the stable version of vlc. Thanks. I think you answered my question. But how do I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: I can convert it into an answer and you can 'accept' it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vlc version 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 has passed the tests for Ubuntu.**

I don't know the details about vlc's daily version, but **usually the daily version of some software means that it is the bleeding edge version**, and still needs testing.

So if you enjoy testing, you can try the daily version, but if you want a reliable tool you should use the version from Ubuntu's repositories, now "2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4".